# How to share 3G connection from Ubuntu to Win7 via WLAN?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have a 3G connection on my Ubuntu 9.10 laptop. Now I want to share it with another laptop using Windows 7. I'm familiar with setting up network connections, but I want to be pointed in the right directions here. I'm not good with iptables and wireless configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this article:

http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/55617

Basically your wireless card is the same, but the `eth0` device in the article should be substituted with whatever device is handling the 3G connection.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! It did not really help though, as Ubuntu does not have all the tools used in that guide (wlanconfig for example).

I found out how to do it using graphical setup and some iptable cut n paste magics.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a proxy server (like squid) on Ubuntu and configure Windows 7 to use the proxy settings for accessing the internet.

I haven't tried them, but here are the instruction to install and configure Squid on Ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid